# How to pre initialize textures in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, textures

I preload and create materials textures before start render and animate of objects.
But THREE JS upload texture to GPU only when object will be shown in camera.
 
So when new object comes on a screen animation is jerking because of texture sends on GPU.
The question is how to send textures to GPU during creation of texture for avoiding it during runtime?
[image]
Loading images to GPU takes a lot of time.

Comment: Does `renderer.compile( scene, camera );` help in your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is to walk your object tree, set each object's `frustumCulled` flag to false, call `renderer.render(scene, ...)` once, then put the flags back to true (or whatever they were).

```
function setAllCulled(obj, culled) {
  obj.frustumCulled = culled;
  obj.children.forEach(child => setAllCulled(child, culled));
}

setAllCulled(scene, false);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
setAllCulled(scene, true);
```

You can also call `renderer.setTexture2D(texture, 0)` to force a texture to be initialized.

Comment: Thank for reply. I like to use renderer.setTexture2D(texture, 0) - frustumCulled - looks strange.

Comment: `setTexture2D` has been removed as of r103

Answer (score 0):

Try `renderer.initTexture(texture: THREE:Texture)` for r0.149.0